# Rails: Create child/parent relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm having trouble adding children to a given parent. The view has an "Add child" link that passes in the current Person object. From here, I'm stuck. Both the parent and child are Person objects.

Also, the logic is poor - it is currently assumes father.

**Model** (person.rb):

```rb
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :children, :class_name => "Person"
  belongs_to :father, :class_name => "Person", :foreign_key => 'father_id'
  belongs_to :mother, :class_name => "Person", :foreign_key => 'mother_id'

  def children
    Person.find(:all, :conditions => ['father_id=? or mother_id=?', id, id])
  end
end
```

**Controller** (people_controller.rb):

```rb
class PeopleController < ApplicationController
  # GET /people/new
  # GET /people/new.xml
  def new
    if (params[:parent_id])
      parent = Person.find(params[:parent_id])
      @person = Person.new(:lastname => parent.lastname, :telephone => parent.telephone, :email => parent.email)
      @person.father.build(:father_id => parent.id)
    else
      # create new
      @person = Person.new
    end

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # new.html.erb
    end
  end


  # POST /people
  # POST /people.xml
  def create
    @person = Person.new(params[:person])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @person.save
        format.html { redirect_to(@person, :notice => 'Person was successfully created.') }
      else
        format.html { render :action => "new" }
      end
    end
  end
end
```

**View** (people/_form.html.erb):

```rb
<%= link_to "Add Child", {:controller => '/people', :action => :new, :parent_id => @person.id} %>
```

Comment: when I click "Add children", populate the form, it saves a new Person. The parent/child relationship is not created.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that right now, you don't actually pass either father_id or mother_id to the "create" action.

The "new" action sets up mother_id/father_id (using build)... but that just means it's there to put into the form on the page... you then have to pass it back to "create" somehow.

Does you form actually contain, say, a hidden field called "father_id" or "mother_id" anywhere?

eg in the template:

```
<% form_for(@person) do |f| %>
  <%= f.hidden_field :father_id %>
  <%= f.hidden_field :mother_id %>
   #everything else here 
<% end %>
```

The hidden fields will only return a value if it's already been set (eg you already do this in the controller #new action) if it hasn't, it will correctly come through as nil anyway.

Comment: Although I don't pass the mother_id/father_id, I am passing a parent_id. The intent is to use this parameter to determine if the parent is father or mother, then build the correct relationship.

Thanks for the explanation regarding "build". Admittedly, I am using it in ignorance.


I had considered using a hidden field, but wasn't sure if this was the best method.

Comment: Ok, but do you populate the parent_id field (on the form) with the value that you put into father_id/mother_id during the new action?
I'll put an example in my answer

Comment: @Taryn: Thanks for the help. I got it working by adding the hidden fields.

Comment: Sorry, also never posted here before.

Comment: No problem - I figured as much. Everybody has to start somewhere ;)